# php not creating file using fopen()

Tags: php

It is always giving the message as "not created". I have checked the permissions and its 777. What to do? It is running perfectly in command line mode.

this is the code:

```
<?php

$msg = "I'm a line that is a message.\n";
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myawesome_logfile.txt';
echo $path;
chmod($path, 0777);

$f = fopen($path, "a+");       //opening or creating the file
if($f)
echo "file created"; 
else
echo "not created";

fwrite($f, $msg);              //writing the file
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: _"I have checked the permissions and its 777"_ Have you checked that the webuser(Apache/nginx) has write access to the folder?

Comment: @Epodax with permissions 777 it doesn't matter because **everybody** has access to the directory.

Comment: @Daan if the file has 777 but the user doesn't have write access in the directory (i.e the folder/directory doesn't have permissions set to 777) it'll be a issue.

Comment: You are providing permissions 777 to path that contains file name. Does this method also make the targeted directory writable.
Just a thought.

Comment: @Epodax true I assumed he made the directory also 777, not that clever though in root.

Comment: @Daan Agreed, but since he can execute the code in command line, I figured it would be a issue with the web user and user permissions for the directory, (Assuming that the command line user and web user is two different users).

Comment: i just checked... and found that apache has the write permission.

Comment: Do you have any warning ? (maybe it's not displayed, check your `error_reporting`). You can also check with `is_writable()` function

Comment: After disabling SElinux it is working perfectly..... is there any other way??